# Concerning posting a ton of questions

Tags: discussion

I have a lot of questions (~10-15) that I asked on the Project Euler forums a while ago that were never answered. Is it alright for me to post them all at once, or should I space them out?

Comment: I'd say space them out; it might be overwhelming to have a pageful of a user's questions for some. But maybe somebody can put forth a convincing argument for "one time big time"...

Comment: It might make sense to space them. If you post them all at once, probably no user will have time to look at all of them, while if they are not posted simultaneously, that would be less of an issue. Assuming that there is some (even) vague thematic similarity between the questions, the spacing would work in your favor.

Comment: I actually looked through them again and including the one I just posted, I only have 4 questions that I consider especially suitable for posting here. I'm guessing that I should still space them out, yes?

Comment: Just post one per day or so. That's fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please do not post them all at once. There is a finite amount of space on the front page, and taking all of it for yourself is extremely rude.

Comment: On the other hand, it *is* extremely thoughtful to pose this question before posting.

Comment: I don't think it's rude. Also, we all know how to click "next page"!

Comment: That's not the point. If the entire front page consists of questions posted by one user, that user is imposing his/her taste on everyone else. We all know how to click "delete," but that doesn't make spam any less annoying or rude.